# Update com foreach na base de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

eu mostro estes dados com o `select` e depois de o utilizador consultar pode editar três campos: **Imagem, Tratamento e Estado**. O campo Estado está a fazer o `update` correto na tabela, mas os campos `input type="file"` e `input type="text"` só fica correto se editar uma linha de cada vez. Este é o código:

```
  $result_cursos = "SELECT centrodb.RegistoManutencao.Id,
       DataRegisto,
       Pedido,
       Outro,
       Descricao,
       Funcionario,
       Imagem,
       Tratamento,
       Estado

FROM centrodb.RegistoManutencao LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.InfoLuvas

ON centrodb.InfoLuvas.Id = centrodb.RegistoManutencao.Colaborador

WHERE Estado IS NULL OR Estado <> 'Concluído';";
    $resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);

$tabela1 .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';

$tabela1 .= '<table border="5">';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .='<thead>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Nº Registo</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Data</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Pedido</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Outro Local</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Descrição</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Colaborador</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Imagem</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Tratamento</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Estado</th>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela1 .='<tbody>';

    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Id'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['DataRegisto'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Pedido'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Outro'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Descricao'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Funcionario'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="file" name= "Imagem" id= "Imagem" value="'.$rows_cursos['Imagem'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" name= "Tratamento" id= "Tratamento" value="'.$rows_cursos['Tratamento'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "Id['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" value="Pendente"> Pendente  <input type="radio" name= "Id['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" value="Concluido">Concluido</td>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
}
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';

echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";

echo $tabela1;

echo "<input type='submit' name='registar' value='Registo'>";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

Onde depois no update crio as variáveis desta forma e faço `update`:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['registar']))
{
$registro = $_POST['Id'];
$tratamento = $_POST['Tratamento'];
$imagem = $_POST['Imagem'];

foreach($registro as $Id => $estado) { 

    $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoManutencao SET Estado='".$estado."', Imagem = '$imagem', Tratamento = '$tratamento' WHERE Id='".$Id."'"); 
} 


}
?>
```

Eu quero que ao editar mais que uma linha, ele faça o `update` correto nas linhas que estou a editar e só faz correto no campo estado. No campo imagem e tratamento só fica correto se fizer o `update` a uma linha de cada vez.

Comment: Poderia contextualizar melhor a pergunta?  Descrevendo o cenário a ser aplicado a solução? , ficou um pouco confuso, se puder descrever acredito que ficará mais fácil da comunidade poder te ajudar

Comment: O problema é que quando estou a fazer o `update` à coluna imagem e tratamento vai buscar sempre a última linha tanto esteja em branco como com dados, porque não sabe o `id` da linha que estou a fazer o `update`

Comment: @Junior Você pode criar botões em cada linha da tabela que fazem a execução do update único(para cada linha que clicar) (isso seria para atualizar imagem e tratamento). Ou você pode tentar enviar a tabela inteira chaveando o nome dos campos para um vetor. Verifique se a forma que você esta fazendo você esta enviando todas as lihas da tabela .  Dê um print_r($_POST) e verifique se vem um vetor de elementos no post. Mais tarde posso fazer um exemplo pra você

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No código altere os `names` dos inputs `Imagem`e `Tratamento`
>
> Na tag form você precisa definir o `enctype` como `"multipart/form-data"` que indica que o formulário que estamos usando
>   vai trabalhar com o envio de arquivos.

```
..................
..................

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="file" name= "Imagem['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" id= "Imagem"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" name= "Tratamento['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" id= "Tratamento" value="'.$rows_cursos['Tratamento'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "Id['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" value="Pendente"> Pendente  <input type="radio" name= "Id['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" value="Concluido"> Concluido</td>';

..................
..................

echo "<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
```

**No update**

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['registar']))
{

$registro = $_POST['Id'];

$tratamento = $_POST['Tratamento'];

    foreach ($registro as $Id => $estado) {

      $imagem = $_FILES['Imagem']['tmp_name'][$Id];
      $tamanho = $_FILES['Imagem']['size'][$Id];
      $fp = fopen($imagem, "rb");
      $conteudo = fread($fp, $tamanho);
      $conteudo = addslashes($conteudo);
      fclose($fp);

        $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoManutencao SET Estado='$registro[$Id]', Imagem = '$conteudo', Tratamento = '$tratamento[$Id]' WHERE Id='".$Id."'");

    }

}
?>
```

<sup>Dessa forma, sendo a coluna do tipo BLOB, salvamos as imagens direto na base de dados. Alguns dos problemas mais citados com relação ao armazenamento de imagens numa base de dados é referente a criação de muita sobrecarga numa busca na base de dados. Sugiro salvá-las externamente em diretórios e apenas manter o endereço (caminho) da imagem na base de dados.</sup>

> variável `$_FILES` utilizada para a leitura de dados dos arquivos que serão enviados para o servidor

$_FILES é um array, desta forma, quando o formulário for submetido, ele terá seus índices que são conforme o  [**site do php**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

```
    $_FILES[name];
    $_FILES[type];
    $_FILES[tmp_name];
    $_FILES[error];
    $_FILES[size];
```

---

### De acordo com o comentário

> No banco de dados quero guardar a url da imagem, porque ocupa menos espaço.

O input não deve ser do tipo file, e sim do tipo `text` para digitar o URL

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" name= "Imagem['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" id= "Imagem"></td>';
```

A coluna no banco deve ser tipo `varchar`

E o PHP é

```
$registro = $_POST['Id'];

$tratamento = $_POST['Tratamento'];

$imagem = $_POST['Imagem'];

    foreach ($registro as $Id => $estado) {

        $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoDiario SET Estado='$registro[$Id]', Imagem = '$imagem[$Id]', Tratamento = '$tratamento[$Id]' WHERE Id='".$Id."'");

    }
```

Comment: desta forma eu envio mesmo a imagem para a base de dados ou faço o upload do caminho para a base de dados?

Comment: @Junior, como na sua pergunta  é `input type="file"`, dessa forma, caso a coluna seja do tipo BLOB, salvamos as imagens direto na base de dados. Alguns dos problemas mais citados com relação ao armazenamento de imagens numa base de dados é referente a criação de muita sobrecarga numa busca na base de dados.  `Sugiro salvá-las externamente em diretórios e apenas manter o endereço (caminho) da imagem na base de dados`.

Comment: eu já estou a guardar o nome da imagem e a extensão, mas como guardo as imagens num diretório externo? porque faço isso mas depois não consigo visualizar as imagens. Eu estou a guardar desta forma: [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277482/guardar-caminho-completo-da-imagem-em-php-e-depois-mostrar-em-uma-tabela/277496#277496)

Comment: pode editar a resposta para eu ver? eu vou fazer upload de fotos tiradas de uma tablet para a base de dados

Comment: Experimentei com o caminho completo e não dá na mesma, a imagem nunca aparece na consulta....podes ver a outra pergunta que fiz, que até coloquei o link no comentário acima, para veres se estou a fazer o update correto do nome e extensão da imagem e depois como posso exibi-la?

Comment: Aqui não pode fazer isso, pois o campo é `input type="file"` e o código está para salvar imagem direto na base de dados.

Comment: @Junior,  antes de tudo tens que decidir o que queres guardar no banco de dados. A imagem? A Url da imagem? Ou ambos os dois (rs, essa é boa, ambos os dois, pois pois)

Comment: No banco de dados quero guardar a url da imagem, porque ocupa menos espaço...

Answer (score 0):

> Exemplo de solução

Pelo o que eu entendi você quer atualizar linha por linha de uma tabela que é montada dinamicamente através de php , Segue o link de um exemplo de como estruturar o seu html para que sua função em php funcione.

**Lembrando**
Este código é apenas um exemplo, uma linha base para você conseguir o que deseja. No código ,note que insiro um formulario para cada linha  e dentro de cada formulario declaro um campo do tipo hidden que armazena o id do registro daquela linha.**Com este código** , cada linha irá fazer uma requisição para o seu arquivo php e você não precisará usar o **foreach**, fazendo com que a atualização seja realizada por demanda : **Ex:**

```
if(isset($_POST['registar']))
{
$registro = $_POST['id'];
$tratamento = $_POST['tratamento'];
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];

    $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoManutencao SET Estado='".$estado."', Imagem = '$imagem', Tratamento = '$tratamento' WHERE Id='".$registro."'");
```

> **Outro Fator Importante!**

Vi que você está inserindo imagens na sua solução, eu não sei de que forma você estruturou seu banco de dados para salvar as imagens,não sei se você está salvando essa imagem em um campo blop ou se está salvando apenas o caminho de uma pasta aonde você move o arquivo. **Se tiver dúvidas sobre como salvar imagens no mysql** utilizando php, indico esse **link** [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/armazenando-imagens-no-mysql/32104)

.Veja o código e tente implementar na sua solução, qualquer outra dúvida poste aqui.

Siga o exemplo :[aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/rdsfelipe/yw0sq1ty/9/)

> Ou veja por aqui:

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Registro</th>
      <th>Imagem</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Tratamento</th>
      <th>Ação</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Registro1</td>
      <form method="post" action="meufile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
      <td><input type="file" name="imagem" /></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="estado" />s | <input type="radio" name="estado" />N</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tratamento"/></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="registrar"value="atualizar" /></td>
      </form>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Registro2</td>
      <form method="post" action="meufile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" />
      <td><input type="file" name="imagem" /></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="estado" />s | <input type="radio" name="estado" />N</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="tratamento"/></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="registrar" value="atualizar" /></td>
      </form>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```