# Guardar nome e extensão da imagem e fazer upload para uma pasta especifica em php e depois mostrar em uma tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ao mostrar uma consulta em uma tabela crio estes três campos para o utilizador fazer o update à linha que mostra os dados da consulta:

```
<?php
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="file" name= "Imagem['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" value="'.$rows_cursos['Imagem'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" name= "Tratamento['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" value="'.$rows_cursos['Tratamento'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="radio" name= "Id['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" value="Pendente"> Pendente  <input type="radio" name= "Id['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" value="Concluido">Concluido</td>';
?>
```

Neste passo seguinte guardo desta forma o caminho da imagem, mas não guarda o caminho completo, só guarda o nome da imagem e o formato "DSCF2712.JPG":

```
    <?php  
    if(isset($_POST['registar']))
    {
    $servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
    $username = "xxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxxxx";
    $dbname = "xxxxxxxx";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $conn->set_charset('utf8');

    $registro = $_POST['Id'];
    $imagem = $_POST['Imagem'];
    $tratamento = $_POST['Tratamento'];


    foreach($registro as $Id => $estado) { 


        $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoManutencao SET Estado='$registro[$Id]', Imagem = '$imagem[$Id]', Tratamento = '$tratamento[$Id]' WHERE Id='".$Id."'"); 
    } 


    }
    ?>
```

Eu estive a pesquisar e pelo que percebi o ideal é só guardar o nome da imagem e a extensão, como tenho, mas agora como faço para a mostrar?
    Estou a fazer desta forma:

```
<?php
$result_cursos = "SELECT centrodb.RegistoManutencao.Imagem FROM centrodb.RegistoManutencao";

$resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);

$tabela1 .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';

$tabela1 .= '<table border="5">';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .='<thead>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Imagem</th>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela1 .='<tbody>';

    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {   

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td><img src="' .$rows_cursos['Imagem']. '" /></td>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
}
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';

echo $tabela1;

?>
```

E o resultado é este, não mostra a imagem, mas se fizer inspecionar ele mostra o nome e a extensão que se encontra na base de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Penso que o problema é não estar a encontrar o caminho completo da imagem

Comment: inspecciona o elemento e ver qual URL está a ser gerada

Comment: Não percebi, podes ser mais especifico?

Comment: Pressione o botão direito do mouse sobre a imagem e vá em inspecionar. Tens certeza que o que está salvando no banco são as bases 64, JPEG?

Comment: Sei que são jpeg, mas no meu caso pode ser também png, precisava de mostrar todas as imagens inseridas na base de dados em tipo de dados `LONGBLOB` na tabela, mas não estou a conseguir

Comment: Me diga que tipo de coluna estás a guardar o URL das imagens.

Comment: neste momento está varchar para guardar o nome da imagem e extensão.

Comment: eu além de guardar o nome da imagem e a extensão na tabela da base de dados, devia colocar um botão para fazer o upload das imagens sempre para uma pasta especifica do servidor. Estou a utilizar o servidor ubuntu server 16.04 e a partilhar pastas com o samba

Comment: Entendo, mas como pode guardar um URL de um campo `input type="file"` ?

Comment: Então em vez de guardar a url, guardar só o nome e a extensão da imagem na tabela da base de dados e guardo numa pasta especifica dentro do servidor, onde o correto devia colocar lá a imagem com um upload e depois mostrar a imagem numa tabela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No PHP**

```
$registro = $_POST['Id'];

$tratamento = $_POST['Tratamento'];

//Pasta onde as imagens serão salvas
$pasta = "img";
//se não existir será criada
if (!file_exists($pasta)){
    mkdir("$pasta", 0777);
}

$diretorio = "img/";

    foreach ($registro as $Id => $estado) {

        $url = $diretorio .  $_FILES['Imagem']['name'][$Id];

        $nome_arquivo = $_FILES['Imagem']['name'][$Id];

        // salva as imagens na pasta
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Imagem']['tmp_name'][$Id], $url);

        // insere o nome com extensão no banco de dados
        $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoDiario SET Estado='$registro[$Id]', Imagem = '$nome_arquivo', Tratamento = '$tratamento[$Id]' WHERE Id='".$Id."'");

    }
```

**No HTML**

> Na tag form você precisa definir o enctype como "multipart/form-data" que indica que o formulário que estamos usando vai trabalhar com o envio de arquivos

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";

$tabela1 .= '<td><img src="img/' .$rows_cursos['Imagem']. '" /></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta faltando o caminho da pas ta imagem,

```
$tabela1 .= '<td><img src="' .$rows_cursos['Imagem']. '" /></td>';
```

isso só funcionaria se sua imagem estiver na mesma pasta do arquivo
se vc usa uma estrutura de pasta de imagens por exemplo que esta junto ao arquivo ve deveria fazer:

```
$tabela1 .= '<td><img src="/imagens/'.$rows_cursos['Imagem']. '" /></td>';
```

Comment: mas eu não carrego as imagens sempre da mesma pasta, depende da imagem....funciona na mesma desta forma? Ou antes de as inserir na base de dados tenho que as colocar numa pasta especifica?

Comment: Apareceu o mesmo resultado com a solução que apresentou. Eu tenho de guardar as imagens numa pasta especifica?

Comment: O padrão é usar uma pasta especifica para as imagens 
pq facilita endereçamento, manutenção e endereçamento.

Comment: Mas tem de ser no servidor ou pode ser no computador do utilizador?

Comment: Inicialmente no servidor, já que o php roda somente no servidor é não no cliente.

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo a fazer um upload para uma pasta especifica dentro do servidor e ao mesmo tempo guardar o nome e a extensão da mesma imagem na tabela da base de dados?