# Alterar o diretório onde a pasta será criada

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu faço desta forma o upload onde cria a pasta dentro da pasta wordpress:

```
if (!file_exists($pasta)){
    mkdir("$pasta", 0777);
}   
    $diretorio = "img/";

foreach ($registro as $Id => $estado) { 

  $url = $diretorio .  $_FILES['Imagem']['name'][$Id];

        $nome_arquivo = $_FILES['Imagem']['name'][$Id];

        // salva as imagens na pasta
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Imagem']['tmp_name'][$Id], $url);
```

Alteração do caminho para a criação da pasta dentro da pasta do tema:

```
$pasta = "/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/img";
if (!file_exists($pasta)){
    mkdir("$pasta", 0777);
}   

$diretorio = "/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/img/";
foreach ($registro as $Id => $estado) { 

  $url = $diretorio .  $_FILES['Imagem']['name'][$Id];

        $nome_arquivo = $_FILES['Imagem']['name'][$Id];

        // salva as imagens na pasta
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Imagem']['tmp_name'][$Id], $url);
```

Agora para exibir as imagens na tabela faço desta forma mas não exibe as imagens:

```
$result_cursos = "SELECT 
       Funcionario,
       Imagem

FROM centrodb.RegistoManutencao LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.InfoLuvas

ON centrodb.InfoLuvas.Id = centrodb.RegistoManutencao.Colaborador

WHERE Estado IS NULL OR Estado <> 'Concluído';";
    $resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);

$tabela1 .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';

$tabela1 .= '<table border="5">';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .='<thead>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Colaborador</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th>Imagem</th>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela1 .='<tbody>';

    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {   

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Funcionario'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td><img src="/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/img/' .$rows_cursos['Imagem']. '" /></td>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 
}}
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';

echo $tabela1;
```

e o resultado é este como mostro na imagem:

Resolvi o problema. O problema está no caminho.
Solução:

```
$tabela1 .= '<td><img src="../img/' .$rows_cursos['Imagem']. '" /></td>';
```

**Se fizer o upload de imagens pelo Windows exibe as imagens na perfeição na parte da consulta, mas se fizer o upload via Android das imagens depois não consigo visualizar as imagens, fico com erro como mostra a imagem acima. O meu código está da forma que mostro na pergunta** Mas a imagem que insiro por Android fica na pasta `img` (faz o upload) e insere o nome e a extensão para a tabela da base de dados. Estou a inserir imagens tiradas pela camera do Android

Criação do campo da imagem:

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="file" name= "Imagem['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" id= "Imagem"></td>';
```

Formulário de inserção da imagem:

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";

echo $tabela1;

echo "<input type='submit' name='registar' value='Registo'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Update na tabela e criação da pasta:

```
$pasta = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/wp-content/themes/busiprof/img";

if (!file_exists($pasta)){
    mkdir("$pasta", 0777);
}   
    $diretorio = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/wp-content/themes/busiprof/img";

foreach ($registro as $Id => $estado) { 

  $url = $diretorio .  $_FILES['Imagem']['name'][$Id];

        $nome_arquivo = $_FILES['Imagem']['name'][$Id];

        // salva as imagens na pasta
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Imagem']['tmp_name'][$Id], $url);

    $conn->query("UPDATE RegistoManutencao SET Estado = '$registro[$Id]', Imagem = '$nome_arquivo', Tratamento = '$tratamento[$Id]' WHERE Id='".$Id."'");
}
```

Exibição da imagem na consulta para o utilizador:

```
$tabela1 .= '<td><<img src="../img/' .$rows_cursos['Imagem']. '" width="600" height="400" alt="CodigoFonte.com.br" onMouseOut="diminui(this)" onMouseOver="aumenta(this)"/></td>';
```

Ao inspecionar a imagem mostra este erro na consola: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Se você tem um arquivo "config" com as variáveis finais, constantes, cria uma com esse caminho.

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo?

Comment: Posso sim. Aguenta aí que já posto, estou sem máquina agora ! Rs

Comment: Este problema já resolvi do caminho, mas continua sem exibir as imagens na tabela onde faz a consulta, vou editar a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está dando um caminho que somente o `servidor` pode acessar diretamente:

`**/var/www/**html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/img`

ou

`**/var/www/html/**wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/img`

Provavelmente colocar 1 desses 3 resolverá:

`wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/img`

`wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/img`

`wp-content/themes/busiprof/img`

Isso por que vai depender de onde está o arquivo PHP.
Se não resolver coloque o nome do seu site na frente ou use uma váriavel `GLOBAL` do PHP:

```
$diretorio = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/wp-content/themes/busiprof/img";
```

Sobre o problema do Android eu precisaria ver o formulário HTML, pode ser que ele nem esteja realmente subindo o arquivo.

Comment: Mas refere-se tanto`ao caminho da criação da pasta como o caminho da exibição da pasta?

Comment: O de exibição, já que este é o problema que você apresentou na dúvida.
caminhos como `htdocs`, `www`, `html` são apenas para apontar arquivos pro servidor, pro cliente o caminho é remoto, començando por HTTPS ou HTTP, que são justamente a virtualização da pasta onde você pode inserir seus scripts PHP e HTML.

Comment: Percebi, obrigado pela explicação e foi com a sua resposta que cheguei à solução. Mas agora tenho outro problema que acrescentei na pergunta acima. Se fizer o upload por windows, funciona tudo bem, mas se fizer o upload pela camera via Android não consigo exibir a imagem

Comment: Sobre o problema do Android eu precisaria ver o formulário HTML, pode ser que ele nem esteja realmente subindo o arquivo.

Comment: Veja nesta pergunta com está o formulário [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277482/guardar-nome-e-extens%C3%A3o-da-imagem-e-fazer-upload-para-uma-pasta-especifica-em-ph) Eu as imagens faço por `update` onde tem a consulta que mostro ao utilizador do pedido de manutenção e depois crio lhe três campos (**Imagem, Tratamento e Estado**) para ele inserir na mesma linha do pedido para dar como concluído o serviço

Comment: Mas a extenção é a mesma que no windows jpg e png, mas nesse caso dá o erro como not found da imagem

Comment: Veja pelo seu gerenciador **FTP** se realmente a imagem está sendo lido e gravada, se a imagem estiver quebrada é por que o seu formulário pode estar usando método errado.
Eu editei a resposta pra mostrar como colocar o protocolo HTTP com o nome do site no caminho da imagem.
Se não der certo vou explicar como fazer upload de um arquivo em BASE64, ou seja, a principio fará por HTML5 (Canvas) depois sim enviará para o conteudo do arquivo convertido.

Comment: Não resolveu o problema, com o Android não mostra a imagem

Comment: Mas a imagem está quebrada no FTP?

Comment: Como vejo isso, se está quebrada?

Comment: A imagem existe na pasta vendo pelo FTP, se sim baixa para sua máquina e se a imagem não aparecer pelo visualizador é por que o conteúdo dela não subiu, somente o arquivo foi criado vazio.

Comment: em cima editei a pergunta para mostrar o formulário que pedia, coloquei todos os passos que faço até à visualização. Mas o upload é bem feito, porque vou dentro da pasta no diretório e ela abre.

Comment: Então se a imagem aparece tente o seguinte, segure o toque na tela do seu Android sobre a imagem que não aparece, quando aparecer o menu selecione para exibir a imagem, veja exatamente a URL que está aparecendo e compare com a do navegador. Eu tenho duas ideias de possiveis erros, e se não der certo  vamos ter que apelar pra BASE64, que infelizmente também não irá funcionar em Androids anteriores ao 4.4.

Comment: Eu quando exibo a imagem não é no android, eu no android faço o upload mas depois não as consigo ver num pc do windows, mas se fizer tanto o upload e a visualização no windows funciona corretamente. Com esta imagem fiz o upload no windows e a visualização no windows e funciona corretamente e este é o caminho `http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/wordpress/img/1.png`. esta fiz o upload no android e não exibe o caminho é `http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/wordpress/img/IMG_20180221_113653.jpg`, diz was not found on this server.

Comment: Já resolvi o problema, eu tinha este caminho `$tabela1 .= '<td><<img src="../img/' .$rows_cursos['Imagem']. '"/></td>';` e a solução é colocar desta forma `$tabela1 .= '<td><<img src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/busiprof/img/' .$rows_cursos['Imagem']. '"/></td>';`